# How to combine ConversationalRetrievalChain with an agent?

Tags: python, langchain

I have a chain which is defined as:

```py
convR_qa = ConversationalRetrievalChain(retriever=customRetriever, 
memory=memory, question_generator=question_generator_chain, 
combine_docs_chain=qa_chain, return_source_documents=True,  
return_generated_question=True, verbose=True )`
```

But now, I want to combine my chain with an agent, where agent can decide whether to retrieve or not depends on the user's intention.
I know there is "Conversational Retrieval Agent" to handle this problem, but I have no idea how to combine my ConversationalRetrievalChain with an agent, as both question_generator_chain and qa_chain are important in my case, and I don't want to drop them.
Thanks for your attention.

I have tried Conversational Retrieval Agent in langchain document. But it is hard to customize for me.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/how_to/custom_agent) so you can build your own custom Agent. If that doesn't help, please provide more information about what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle with "How to decide to retrieve or not when using ConversationalRetrievalChain", I have a another solution rather than using "Conversational Retrieval Agent", which is token-consuming and not robust.
A new LLMChain called "intention_detector" is defined in my ConversationalRetrievalChain, taking user's question as input.
Then it will decide:

```
intention = self.intention_detector.run(question=question)
```

return true or false. The prompt template of intention_detector behaves like:

```
PROMPT_FEW_SHOTS_INTENTION_DETECTION = FewShotPromptTemplate(
examples=_intention_detection_examples, 
example_prompt=_intention_detection_prompt_template, 
prefix="Please judge does user's query be related to knowledge in specific domain. Return True or False.",
suffix="Input: {question}\nOutput: ", 
input_variables=["question"]
```

)

Fewshots examples are given above depending on your demand.
Then, another LLMChain can handle with:

```
PROMPT_CHAT_HISTORY = ChatPromptTemplate.from_messages([
SystemMessage(content="Refer to the chat_history and answer the latest question."), 
MessagesPlaceholder(variable_name="chat_history"),
HumanMessagePromptTemplate.from_template("{question}"),
```

])

Therefore, our ConversationalRetrievalChain bahaves much more smart, like:

```
Human: Who are you?
AI(answer directly): I am an AI Assistant. How can I help you?
```

And if you propose some professional issues:

```
Human: Is biyadi worth investing in?
(After retrieving the vectorDB)
AI: Refer to the infomation provided by GF Securities, biyadi launches a lot new ......
```

And finally, we can end the conversation:

```
Human: Thanks for your help!
AI(answer directly): You are welcome!
```

Here our ConversationalRetrievalChain can distinguish human's intention, choosing to retrieve the vectorDB or not.

Comment: This looks interesting, can u please help me with sequence of steps in terms of coding, how to use the templates, intention with ConversationalRetrievalChain.from_llm() ?

Comment: hello Cehao Yang,
would you mind sharing a coding sample to this implementation?